# How does range query work in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Query I would like to fire

```
select * from t1 where c1 > 1000 and c2 > 1Million and c3 > 8Million
```

Data model of table t1

```
create table t1 {
    c1 int,
    c2 int,
    c3 int,
    c4 text
}
```

Which columns should I use as partition key and which as clustering key.
c1 , c2 , c3 can have value between 1 to 10 Million.

If I do primary key ((c1,c2,c3)) then the values will be spread across cluster. But as I fire > queries on c1,c2,c3 columns how does Cassandra know which nodes to contact or does it do a full shard scan?

Answer (score 2):

It wont allow you to make that query without an `ALLOW FILTERING` which lets it read entire dataset because its throughout the cluster. It would read everything, throwing things away that don't match. Its highly recommended never to use `ALLOW FILTERING` outside dev/test unless really sure what your doing.

Answer (score 1):

Partition keys can only be filtered with equalities, not inequalities such as the ones you have. Inequalities can only be used with clustering keys.

If your table does not have that many rows, you can use the bucket strategy. With it you create a auxiliary column to be the only partition key with a predefined value (such as 1).

```
create table t1 {
    bucket int,
    c1 int,
    c2 int,
    c3 int,
    c4 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (bucket, c1, c2, c3)
}
```

Because you have a single partition, it is not adequate for scaling tables with many rows.

If you do have many rows, which you need to partition, then you have to rethink your strategy, and think about:

- Finding some kind of key (or keys) in the data that is able to partition the data and at the same time help filtering it when needed. Then you would use it as the partition key in the example above. Maybe denormalizing the data can help bring that key (Ex.: Creating a column called Status for Low/Medium/High numbers, which you could filter better later in the inequality filtering of the clustering keys).
- Plan a table (or tables) to be queried by an analytics framework such as Spark. In analytics it's common the need to query by any column, with equalities or inequalities.